# Availability of Azure Media Services Job notifications in Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I want to get job change notifications from Azure Media Services using Storage queue. I read the statement *It is also possible that some state change notifications get skipped* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-check-job-progress-with-queues).

Can someone tell me how reliable is this service ?. Is it a very small percentage of all messages or is it quite visible ?

Answer (score 0):

We do not provide a guarantee on delivery, but I would say that it is highly reliable.

There are cases where notifications can get dropped (a storage outage so that Media Services cannot deliver notifications to a queue for an extended period of time for example).  I would recommend that you have a fallback plan that if a job hasn’t been updated by notification for some expected duration, that you have backup code to GET the job details from the API directly.

The “expected duration” is a little bit difficult to predict since job processing times vary by operation and input content size/complexity.  There also can be queuing depending on the number of jobs submitted and the number of reserved units you have.

Hope that helps,

John